# I have django rest_framework ListAPIView method which returns me list of users, how I can exclude requesting user from the same user list

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views

> serializers.py

```py
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.CustomUser
        fields = ('username', 'email', 'is_active','is_superuser')
```

> views.py

```py
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.CustomUser.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
```

---

I am using auth token for the URLs, so I will have user token in headers from which I can identify and exclude, this is what I wanted to try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override `get_queryset` as follows

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
    def get_queryset(self):
        return CustomUser.objects.exclude(email=self.request.user.email)
```

I have not tested the code, but the idea is correct.

Comment: `self.request.user` will return the ***user instance***, not a `string` representing the `email`

Comment: then request.user.email :)

Comment: You are supposed to change that in your answer :)

Answer (score 0):

just use exclude instead of all(), just modify your code to something like this

```
class UserListView(generics.ListAPIView):
    queryset = models.CustomUser.objects.exclude(username=request.username)
    serializer_class = serializers.UserSerializer
```

Comment: If you use this, it evaluated only once and after a while the view may return invalid result.

Comment: @a_k_v   didn't quite get you why after a while the view may return invalid result?

Comment: When you set queryset, the queryset is created only once, when you start your server. On the other hand, the get_queryset method is called for every request.

Comment: no, it doesn't work like that every call to this view will fetch new querset

Comment: check https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/optimization/  for reference

Comment: From the doc i saw the preferred way is override get_queryset for dynamic filtering !! https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/

Comment: django is built on DRY principle, in the docs it says -- another common need is to filter down the objects given in a list page by some key in the URL. Earlier we hard-coded the publisher’s name in the URLconf, but what if we wanted to write a view that displayed all the books by some arbitrary publisher?

Comment: I found a similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51029653/the-queryset-attribute-of-django-rest-api-generic-views